# #name error when using custom function excel addin js web office in 1120.3.2.3 Online Firefox

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

I have created a custom function in the Excel office add-in and it's working fine with the local network, edge browser, and Mac but in Mozilla Firefox its give the error which is **"#name"**,

I don't know why but it's happening only at Mozilla.
I have used a shared run time environment for custom function It worked fine with the local host but when I used the server manifest file it showed **#name**.

i have used **Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"**

and i am getting **Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sfjlemon.ifour-consultancy.net/functions.json.** in the console.log.

[image: this is the my function name]

[image: this error occurred]

Comment: I'm not clear on what the correlation is. Does the problem correlate with the browser or does it correlate with whether the server is localhost or remote?

Comment: Have you tried debugging tools available in a web browser to see how the code is loaded and triggered?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: @RickKirkham its a remote server and I a getting the **Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sfjlemon.ifour-consultancy.net/functions.json. ** in the console this happening when I am using Microsoft edge and Mozilla firefox.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers yes this is https

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev yes I have used a debugger its files are decrypted as its in the server